# Vega-Lite: Map from Amsterdam not show

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Hi guys I'm trying to create a map from Amsterdam using a very basic code, but the map didn't show up:

```
{
 "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
 "width": 700,
 "height": 500,
 "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}},
 "data": {
   "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minhquan9408/gdv_1/main/data/map.topojson",
   "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
 },
 "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "white", "strokeWidth": 2},
 "encoding": {"color": {"value": "#eee"}}
}
```

But when I use data from Berlin it worked as expected

```
{
 "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
 "width": 700,
 "height": 500,
 "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}},
 "data": {
   "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/funkeinteraktiv/Berlin-Geodaten/master/berlin_bezirke.topojson",
   "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
 },
 "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "white", "strokeWidth": 2},
 "encoding": {"color": {"value": "#eee"}}
}
```

here is the [online Vega-Lite Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDsABh1L4NMljQBWPUqhyAZkbShiNOMvsgImAE5sA1nDQhPJFkIHCQPOFlMEABfaKU1JEwUVFAGD0F-LFx8Ig8kZWo6RiYGCDgPK0iIzEorBAIEGlkYAEcGIIBOMR0ADgIyNWIAfQBGBqQmggSk8ZxKTDYcNmk5RRBrNg9kKJSAgE8cP3QFpZX5JWs4RLSjtyTMOAgYuJBkD29XTAPbsjg2CBgSEOa3cXl8-mUMBEIM8PjgAHV1JpUAAmF4RKxqJpkVxWQSbVzEJCCBi3ADEcEpz2iQA)

Anyone knows the anwser for this problem? I think it's probably because of the data. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is registered in a cartesian projection (meters) and not in a geographic projection (degrees).

The following Vega-lite spec provide the proper way to visualise this type of data. Note the `identity` projection and `reflectY` parameter setting.

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minhquan9408/gdv_1/quan-new/data/map.topojson",
    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "collection"}
  },
  "mark": {"type": "geoshape"},
  "projection": {"type": "identity", "reflectY": true}
}
```

[image]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDsABh1L4NMljQBWPUqhyAZkbShiNOMvsgImAE5sA1nDQhPJFkIHCQPOFlMEABfaKU1JEwUVFAGD0F-LFx8Ig8kZWo6RiYGCDgPK0iIzEorBAIEGlkYAEcGIIBOMR0ADgIyNWIAfQBGAjag-llnAgSkhqQcSkw2HDZpOUUQazYPZCiUgIBPHD90FbWN+SVrOES0s5ArQUE4KEx2eVilZA9vV0wJ0eZDgbAgMEWfiU7i8vn8yhgIi2MJ8cAA6upNKgAExxEARKxqJpkVzPXauYhIQQMR4AYjgDJieJwXkkbw+m0OgNO-nU1ToRy24Wsr3eAE00J4abEgA)

I've to admit, you probably never could have guessed this..

Comment: thank you very much. I have no clue about this issue because I could not find anything related to this in Vega Lite Documents. Wish you all the best !

Answer (score 0):

Your topojson file does not have a geometry collection named `"states"`, but it does have one named `"collection"`. Changing this makes the file load and display correctly:

```json
{
 "width": 700,
 "height": 500,
 "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}},
 "data": {
   "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minhquan9408/gdv_1/main/data/map.topojson",
   "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "collection"}
 },
 "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "white", "strokeWidth": 2}
}
```

[image]

The result is obviously not what was intended, but this appears to be a data quality issue rather than a Vega-Lite issue: other topojson viewers also show it to include a geometry that covers the entire map.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I have already uploaded the file on geojson.io and it shows the map correctly. Actually I converted the original geojson data from [https://maps.amsterdam.nl/open_geodata/](https://maps.amsterdam.nl/open_geodata/geojson.php?KAARTLAAG=GEBIEDEN22&THEMA=gebiedsindeling) to topojson. So do you know how can we check the quality of a topojson data?

Comment: Data is fine. It's just not stored in degrees, but in meters. While Vega-lite defaults to displaying maps in degrees it can do it as well in meters, but not so intuitive. For full answer see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65836008/2459096

Comment: Actually the file you referring in the URL is in degrees. You probably have changed the projection during processing and got bitten by the winding order. You can see here https://mattijn.github.io/topojson/example/settings-tuning.html#winding_order how this influences the rendering in Vega-Lite (scroll a bit down)